# ExtJS toolbar load items

Tags: ajax, json, extjs

I need to load items (menu) via ajax but do not understand how...
trying to do like this:

```
var tb = Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', { 
        renderTo: 'top-menu', 
        autoLoad: { 
            url: '/index/tullbar', 
            renderer: 'component', 
            params: { 
                userId: 1 
            } 
        }, 
        layout: { 
            overflowHandler: 'Menu' 
        } 
    }); 

});
```

response:

```
[
    {
        "text": "test",
        "menu": {
            "text": "asdf",
            "handler":"handleAction.createDelegate(window)"
        }
    }
]
```

but handler is not working.
Can anybody give the working example.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used element loader before so I would make a wild guess that you should specify a renderer function according to http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/-cfg-renderer:

```
var tb = Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', { 
    renderTo: 'top-menu', 
    autoLoad: { 
        url: '/index/tullbar', 
        renderer: function(loader, response) {
            var menuItems = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
            tb.items.add(menuItems);
        }, 
        params: { 
            userId: 1 
        } 
    }, 
    layout: { 
        overflowHandler: 'Menu' 
    } 
});
```

Comment: your example raise error:
`code`comp.getItemId is not a function

Comment: tied with: `renderer: 'component',`
and replace the server answer by: `[{"text":"test","menu":{"text":"asdf","listeners":{"click":{"fn":"function () {alert('halo')}"}}}}]`
it create button but when clicking the button `me.el is undefined`

Comment: @Subdigger Ok, sorry if I confused you. I haven't used autoLoad before. Didn't find any good example of it neither.